# How to count or draw the matched track only using python for two different images

Tags: images, python, tracking

I need to count the number of matched track in two figures. As you can see in figure "T140-1.jpg" the matched track (red and black) are staying close to each other. Since the number is too small I can count manually. But in real case I have more than 70000 tracks in each file and then need to draw and count the total number of matched  tracks while combined both.

Would you please help me to solve this problem. It can be mention that i draw the images form csv file using python. So I also want to count the number using python. Thanks in advance for your kind co-operation.

[image: T140.jpg]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. Considering you're aware of that: Are you looking for a library/module to use with your Python development?